# How to stop Jmeter test after specified number of threads failed

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have one Transaction controller which has one http request in my Jmeter test plan. Transaction name and url comes from CSV file. At the end total execution is divided into 5 different transactions.

Testplan:

Testplan
 -Thread Group
  - User defined variable

Total sample execution will be 8000-10000. Now what i want, if total sample failures reached to 100, my JMeter test should stop test execution.

I have added User defined variable name "thread" and with value "0". I have added below code in Beanshell Post-Processor

```
int count= Integer.parseInt(vars.get("thread"));
if (prev.getErrorCount()==1){
count++;
System.out.println(count);
vars.put("thread",Integer.toString(count));
}

if (count==100){

System.out.println("Reached to max number of errors in load test, stopping test");
log.info ("Reached to max number of errors in load test, stopping test");
prev.setStopTestNow(true);

}
```

Somehow code is not working as expected. When error count reach to 100, Jmeter test is not getting stopped. Test is stopped when error count reached to 130. I am not sure who to fix above code.

Can someone please let me know what is issue in above code?

Comment: Do you have nested samples?

Comment: If i run it for single user and keep error count limit to 3, it works fine. Test stopped after 3 failuers.  But when i run it for 5 Users, with max error count s 3, Test stop after 8 failures.

It’s simple script. No nested samples.

Comment: Have you tried to use props instead of 'vars'?

Comment: No i did not. Could you please share some details on that?

Comment: props is global while vars is localised to the thread. Because I can't try it myself I won't recommend it as an answer, but if it works for you I'll can give a better explanation.

Comment: I am not sure where i need to use props. https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getErrorCount()........this api gives me error count. I am storing it in User defined variable which i set to '0' before starting the test. Then i am comparing it with some predefined count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83089/discussion-between-ross-and-user1169236).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are specific to 1 thread while Properties are shared by all threads.

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)
- https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Ensure you synchronize access

Another option is to use a custom java class as a Singleton and increment its value.

Here an example implementation using Beanshell (Prefer JSR223 + Groovy for performances):

- setupThreadGroup that resets the counter on test start:[image]
- BeanshellPostProcessor that updates counter:[image]

Note that as you call setStopTestNow, test threads are interrupted but do not stop exactly at this time unless you have some timer (which is usually the case)

> prev.setStopTestNow(true);

Comment: Yes i am working on it. But looks like i am doing something wrong. I have added declared as property but still facing same issue            String count1 = props.setProperty("abc","0");
String thread = props.getProperty("abc");

int count= Integer.parseInt(vars.get("thread"));
if (prev.getErrorCount()==1){
count++;
System.out.println(count);
vars.put("thread",Integer.toString(count));
}

if (count==3){

System.out.println("Reached to max number of errors in load test, stopping test");
log.info ("Reached to max number of errors in load test, stopping test");
prev.setStopTestNow(true);

}

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. Above solution i have tried and it worked :). I appreciate your help.